# Error Deploying Laravel App to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a relatively simple Laravel app onto AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I go through the normal processes on prepping the Laravel app prior to compressing:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

I also make sure all of the `.env` variables are set to their production values.

Because the app is small enough, I tend to leave `/vendor` and `/node_modules` in the compressed app bundle that is uploaded so that I don't have to SSH into the instance to run any composer or npm commands.

I select the obvious options with the ELB application and environment: select PHP configuration, upload my source bundle, and set the root directory to `/public`.

The above steps work about 25% of the time. 75% of the time, the instance goes into either Error or Severe status and I have to try and create a new environment.

I'm not sure what is going wrong or even where to find logs of the problem. The logs in the ELB log area just say something like "you can't request logs when the app is not in a ready state", etc...

Comment: Can you show me the file sturucture

Comment: @KumarPraveen added!

Comment: show the syntax of error what error its throws. can you share url

Comment: Here is one warning: `Create environment operation is complete, but with command timeouts. Try increasing the timeout period. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.` --- Well I did increase the timeout period from 10 minutes to 30 minutes and after that it just failed after 30 minutes instead of after only 10.

Comment: did you restart the instance after changing the time

Comment: can you send me the url of you app

Comment: Yes I have redeployed the instance and also tried creating many new instances with the increased timeout period. The problem is probably from something underlying which is causing the deployment to stall, but the actual fail occurs whenever the timeout period ends. Unfortunately I can't send the url of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was the `/node-modules` directory and the files `package.json` and `package-lock.json`. The reason is that upon deployment, Elastic Beanstalk was trying to execute `npm update` or a similar command.

These files are only necessary for front-end development and not required to be deployed on the server. In development, webpack is used to compile them into app.js, which I then post to S3. So none of those front-end development files need to be on the production server whatsoever.

For good measure, I also excluded `composer.json` and `composer.lock` because I don't need to run `composer update` during deployment.